# How to align span right and when overflow show ellipsis?

Tags: html, css

I have the following situation:

[image]

But what I want to do is align right of my container, and if text overflows his container, show ellipsis, instead of now which the alignment is from left.

My expectation:

```
              AAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBB...
              CCC
```

And in cases where the first or third line contains more characters:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAA...
BBBBBBBBBBBBBB...
              CCC
```

Comment: Please post the code to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
.box {
  display: inline-block;
}

p {
  width: 80px;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-align: right;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
  <p>AAAAAAAAAAAAAA</p>
  <p>BBBBBBBBBBBBBB</p>
  <p>CCC</p>
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/122/)**

Answer (score 1):

Using pure CSS, add these attriutes:

```
 text-align:right;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

`text-align:right;` aligns your text to the right.

`overflow: hidden;` plus `text-overflow: ellipsis;` will make text overflow and be replaced by an ellipsis.

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/qmyyLr0f/)